# Stencil theme js not applying on live site

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I have been working on a bigcommerce stencil theme for a couple months and today I modified some js for the thumbnail slider. I can see that after running the `stencil bundle` and uploading my theme that only my `js` changes are not making it. All my `scss` and template changes are there but the `js` never makes it.

This is what I am modifying:

`$('.product-images-pagination').slick({
   infinite: false,
   dots: false,
   arrows: true,
   slidesToShow: 4,
   slidesToScroll: 3,
   variableWidth: false,
   asNavFor: '.product-slides-wrap',
   focusOnSelect: true,
  });`

And on the server this is what I see:

`(".product-images-pagination").slick({
    infinite:!0,
    dots:!1,
    arrows:!1,
    slidesToShow:5,
    slidesToScroll:1,
    variableWidth:!0,
    asNavFor:".product-slides-wrap",
    focusOnSelect:!0
})}}])`

Clearly the changes are not making it and I dont know why. Please help me if you can.

Comment: Where are you placing this JS in your theme?

Comment: This is the theme file /assets/js/theme/product/ProducImages.js and all I did was modify the options being passed to `.slick()`

Comment: Try 1) Removing Users\usernameAppData\Roaming\npm\node-modules 
2) Re-installing stencil-cli. The path will be different if you are on a mac.

Comment: Is that globally on my mac or in the project? I havent been on windows in a long time but I'm thinking thats a windows path to the global npm right? Then after I do this rebundle the theme and see if that works? I appreciate the help.

Comment: I got rid of bigcommerce/stencil-cli, reinstalled, rebundled the theme and uploaded it and it still hasnt changed :(

Comment: So I think the problem is the bundle.js is not updating after I stencil bundle, its not updating that file at all.